# Can not reach .Net gRPC server on Cloud Run #1653

Tags: .net, grpc, google-cloud-run

I was trying to have a .Net Kestrel gRPC server deployed on Cloud Run. But cannot work properly.

My local environment is `MacOS Big Sur Version 11.6.4`.

To reproduce:

1. Create a new gRPC project by selecting `gRPC Service` template on Visual Studio for mac 2022 Preview
2. Change `Program.cs` as below:

```
using GrpcGreeter.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
// For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc();


var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT") ?? "8080";
var url = $"http://0.0.0.0:{port}";

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

app.Run(url);
```

3. add `Dockerfile` from [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-s
   amples/blob/main/run/helloworld/Dockerfile).
4. Build docker image. `docker build -t gcr.io/my-project/grpc-greeter .`
5. Docker run locally `docker run --rm -p 12345:8080 gcr.io/my-project/grpc-greeter`
6. Check by using `grpcurl`. (Error message was shown but works fine because `grpcurl` has reached my application)

```
$ grpcurl -plaintext 0.0.0.0:12345 list
Failed to list services: server does not support the reflection API
```

7. Push docker image on GCR: `docker push gcr.io/my-project/grpc-greeter`
8. Deploy to Cloud Run by using this command:

```
gcloud run deploy grpc-greeter --image gcr.io/my-project/grpc-greeter --port 5000 --use-http2 --region us-central1
```

9. Run `grpcurl` again then you will see following error message. This request could not reach this application so that Cloud Run console did not show any logs.

```
$ grpcurl -plaintext my-project.a.run.app:443 list
Failed to dial target host "my-project.a.run.app:443": context deadline exceeded
```

Thank you for reading and please any help.

----- Added Mar. 7th --------------

I faced the same log message that troubleshoots said: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#sandbox

Log explore shows this message:

```
{
  "textPayload": "Container Sandbox: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x7a,0x1,0xd,0x3dfb18bfeef8,0x8,0x3dfb0800ac78). It is very likely that you can safely ignore this message and that this is not the cause of any error you might be troubleshooting. Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/compatibility/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more information.",
  "insertId": "6224c2a80009b0975ebc347b",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "revision_name": "grpc-greeter-00005-ziq",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "service_name": "grpc-greeter",
      "project_id": "my-project",
      "configuration_name": "grpc-greeter"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-03-06T14:18:16.634974567Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "00bf4bf02d3ed790c520d7b323e25ad7bbc2a7a5044f2372a67f11aa5ec3aad8379c3ed7976eda29dba06f978dc44b6a9635786f2c6a33dae4991695"
  },
  "logName": "projects/my-project/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-03-06T14:18:16.639213876Z"
}
```

Comment: You want to drop `--plaintext` when you're hitting a Cloud Run endpoint because it will be using TLS.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the Cloud Run (service's) logs too. Please add these to your question.

Comment: Thanks, Finally, I reached my gRPC server!

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!